# Getting error INFO [SocketServer brokerId=3] Failed authentication with /10.2.***.* (SSL handshake failed) (org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector)

Tags: kubernetes, kafka

I have kafka multibroker deployed on kubernetes, with interbroker SSL communication, I have set the folowing properties:

```
advertised.listeners=SSL://kafka-1.**.***.com:9093,PLAINTEXT://kafka-1.**.******.com:9092
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper-0.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:2181,zookeeper-1.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:2181,zookeeper-2.zookeeper-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:2181
broker.id=1
ssl.keystore.location=/opt/kafka/config/tls/kafka.server.keystore.jks
ssl.keystore.password=password
ssl.key.password=password
ssl.truststore.location=/opt/kafka/config/tls/kafka.server.truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=password
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=
ssl.client.auth=requested
```

Same configuration is for the other brokers with changed broker ids and advertsied listeners

I had created the certificates with the CN as kafka-1.**.***.com
I am not able to figure out what causing this error?